# Where are Debian packages hosted?

Tags: debian, packages, repository

I want to install a package (`libappindicator3-dev`) but it's not showing up for me when I try install it -- I'm using the sid/testing repository, so it should be there:

http://packages.debian.org/sid/libappindicator3-dev

So I was wondering if it's possible to download the .deb package directly without using APT, and install it with dpkg.

I'm struggling to find the URL where the packages are located at though, I tried something like:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/sid/main/

But there's no packages there and I only see information files. Could anyone possibly tell me where to find the .deb packages from the repositories? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right in the link you provided. Under http://packages.debian.org/sid/libappindicator3-dev, click on the name of your computer's architecture (probably [amd64](http://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libappindicator3-dev/download) or [i386](http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libappindicator3-dev/download)) and click on one of the mirrors. This gives you the `.deb` file which you can install directly. (You may also have to download its dependencies if they're not in the repo APT is seeing.)

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that section at the end of the package page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install a local package with

```
dpkg -i <package-name>
```

This adds the package to the local package database as well, so upgrading will work as you expect. You'll need to be root to install with dpkg.