# Where are the packages in Debian?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I come from Ubuntu and have recently started using Debian.

So far, I tried to install with:

```
apt-get install gedit
```

but also emacs, python 3, mozilla, wicd and many other pretty common packages.

Where are they?

Comment: ? http://superuser.com/questions/454222/where-are-debian-packages-hosted

Comment: In the debian repository. You will see the links when it is being downloaded.

Comment: Do you mean the packages won't install, as in they are missing, where are they? or how are they found on the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed Debian from a CD-ROM without network connection. Debian could not verify the repositories, therefore it commented them out. These are the lines with # at the beginning in the /etc/apt/sources.list file.

Probably you also have a line for a CD-ROM repository that looks like 'deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux...' On this one, you can put a # at the beginning, unless you have CDs with packages at hand (which you probably don't have, since you are asking how to find them).

So, to solve your problem, just open /etc/apt/sources.list as root and un-comment lines that begin with '# deb http...' (Not all #s should be removed, since some are just comments).

Now you will be able to install with apt-get like in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Add some, or all, of these lines to your file /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
  deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
  deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

  deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
  deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

  # wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
  deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
  deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-proposed-updates contrib non-free main
  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
  deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
  deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
  #deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
  #deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
  #deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```